# Can not create nodester account

Tags: node.js, installation, nodester

I want to register on http://nodester.com/. I got my coupon, registered on site, installed **nodester** (npm install nodester-cli -g)

and user setup command (*nodester user setup gio.beri@gmail.com pass****) gives me error:

```
nodester info verifying credentials
```

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodester-cli/node_modules/nodester-api/node_modules/request/vendor/cookie/index.js:45
    : url.parse(req.url).pathname;
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at new Cookie (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodester-cli/node_modules/nodester-api/node_modules/request/vendor/cookie/index.js:45:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodester-cli/node_modules/nodester-api/node_modules/request/main.js:432:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodester-cli/node_modules/nodester-api/node_modules/request/main.js:426:46)
    at Request.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodester-cli/node_modules/nodester-api/node_modules/request/main.js:391:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
    at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1231:22)
    at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:303:27)

Can anyone suggest anything?

**EDIT:**
I think that problem is in my password. what must me there coupon???

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I've updated to verson 0.6.2 but the same error. And additionally gives "The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface." error. what is the working verison?

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not getting that error. You should post an issue to nodester https://github.com/nodester/nodester/issues